# Getting error in PHP CodeSniffer

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

When I try to open a file in PHPStorm(10.0.3) getting following message.

```
phpcs: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHP_CodeSniffer_File::recordMetric() in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/PSR2/Sniffs/Files/ClosingTagSniff.php on line 91
```

Is anyone know whats this?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 3):

#### Upgrading Code Sniffer fixed this error for me.

I had a similar error and found that I was using an old version (1.5) of code sniffer. I then used pear to install it and now am on version 2.5.1 and the error is gone.

Not sure what OS you are using but for Ubuntu I used:

```
pear install --alldeps php_codesniffer
```